# MySQL query optimisation - field on the left or right?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I <strike>know</strike> think that I've read that one of the following is faster than the other, but I forget which is which:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myDate` > NOW();
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE NOW() < `myDate`;
```

Answer (score 3):

The optimizer will produce the same execution plan, realizing that the constant is the same on both sides.

Comment: I hope it doesn't matter. Otherwise, MySQL is a crock!